# What JSON LD syntax to use to display a company icon with an email in Google Inbox/Gmail

Tags: email, json-ld, google-inbox

When using json ld to markup an email, what JSON LD schema must be used to display a company icon with your email in Google Inbox/Gmail.

I've tried setting multiple props as follows, but Google does not recognise the metadata.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json" >
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "EmailMessage",
            "description": "Test!",
            "image": "https://apiant.com/appResources/icons_large/shopify.png",
            "thumbnailUrl": "https://apiant.com/appResources/icons_large/shopify.png",
            "sender": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "name",
                "logo": "https://apiant.com/appResources/icons_large/shopify.png",
                "brand": {
                    "name": "name"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Relevant docs:

- http://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/formats/json-ld‌​.
- http://schema.org/EmailMessage

Comment: Which of Google’s email features do you try to get? Did you read the relevant documentation for that feature?

Comment: Google's docs are here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/formats/json-ld. They follow the https://schema.org/EmailMessage standard which is what I have tried to implement without success.

Comment: I mean a feature that makes use of the `logo` property. If Gmail displays the logo sometimes, I’d guess they have this documented. And in that documentation, it should be noted how `logo` has to be specified. What you currently have is perfectly fine as far as Schema.org is concerned, but Google typically has more restrictive rules.

Comment: I think that is the heart of the issue. Google's documentation from the link above does not appear to specifically mention my use case. However, I've seen many examples of emails within my Google inbox account that includes emails with company icons so there must be a solution, whether it is JSON LD based or not. Hoping to use this question to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way is to create a Gmail or Google Apps account with the same email as the sender email and add a photo to that profile:

https://postmarkapp.com/blog/how-to-easily-add-a-sender-image-to-gmail#adding-a-sender-image-to-gmail